# Is there a single word to describe a 'student of life'?

Tags: phrase-requests, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes somebody who is always learning and interested in acquiring more knowledge. A word that encapsulates 'knowledge seeker', 'student of life', 'avid learner'. I'm currently trying to create a pseudonym and have been trying to find words that encapsulate the image I'm trying to portray. I've looked at different name meanings, but I'm leaning more toward creating a name from a word that's not a "traditional name".